# do_shortcode close

Tags: custom-field, loop, shortcode

I am using the jscrollpane plugin on WordPress along with the advanced custom fields plugin. The jscrollpane plugin uses the following shortcodes:

```
[vr_jsp]
[/vr_jsp]
```

I have two different custom fields that I need to put between their own set of the above shortcodes which are:

```
<?php the_field('first_content_block'); ?>
<?php the_field('second_content_block'); ?>
```

I understand you can use the below code to do this but I am a bit stuck on what to use to output the custom field between the two shortcodes.

```
<?php echo do_shortcode('[vr_jsp]CONTENT HERE[/vr_jsp]'); ?>
```

Just to clarify I need the custom field (first_content_block) displayed where 'CONTENT HERE' is.

Comment: [`get_field`](http://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/functions/get_field/)

Comment: Could you show me a working example using the code provided? Sorry to be awkward

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use get_field instead of the_field. That way you can assign it to a varilable.

```
$first_comment = get_field('first_content_block');
$second_comment = get_field('second_content_block');

echo do_shortcode("[vr_jsp] $first_comment, $second_comment [/vr_jsp]");
```

I haven't tried it, but see if that works.

Comment: Perfect! makes more sense now. Thank you for the easy to understand explnation!